# How to put a list of data table in a list of objects

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a data table in my feature file, which I want to convert to a list of objects. The problem is data table has headers, which are supposed to be set in the value of objects. As an example:

```
| ANNOTATION_TYPE_ID | ANNOTATION_SUBTYPE_ID | PAGE_NB | LEFT_NB | TOP_NB | WIDTH_NB | HEIGHT_NB | FONTSIZE_NB | COLOR_X | ANNOTATION_TEXT_X |
|                  1 |                     1 |       1 |     400 |    200 |       88 |        38 |          15 | FFFFFF  | TEST Annotation   |
|                  2 |                     2 |       1 |     150 |    150 |       88 |        38 |          20 | FFFFF0  | TEST Annotation   |
```

This I want to convert to a list of objects as List annotations where Annotation is a class and the headers of the above data table are essentially the field variables inside the class.
What is the efficient way to do this?
The moment I convert data table to list (`List<String> annotationList = annotation.asList(String.class))`, it becomes a big set and how to group them is what I am struggling with?

Comment: Is this Java? If so please [edit] your question to include the proper language tag

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to look at this as a list of annotations, with each annotation having a set of key/value pairs based upon each row in your file.  It would look like List of HashMaps where each HashMap key is the row header value and the value is the row value.  This may not be the most efficient approach depending upon your usage.  Here's sample code that was able to parse the data you provided - it produces a List with two items, each has a HashMap with the number of key/values for the columns above. Good luck.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path filePath = Path.of("C:\\tmp\\anno");
        if (!Files.exists(filePath)) {
            System.out.println("File does not exist at '" + filePath + "'");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        List<HashMap<String, String>> annotations = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        try {
            List<String> annoFile = Files.readAllLines(filePath);
            List<String> headers = Arrays.asList(annoFile.remove(0).split("\\|"));
            headers.forEach(System.out::println);

            while (annoFile.size() > 0) {
                List<String> rowValues = Arrays.asList(annoFile.remove(0).split("\\|"));
                HashMap<String, String> annotation = new HashMap<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < headers.size(); i++) {
                    if (rowValues.size() >= i) {
                        annotation.put(headers.get(i).strip(), rowValues.get(i).strip());
                    }
                }
                annotations.add(annotation);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```